# Calling a method according to a timer set by the user

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on a JSF application that connects with Twitter.
In one of my views, I have a button that when clicked, calls a method that connects with a Twitter account retrieving new tweets and doing some processing on them.

Next to the button I want to let the user to set a timer in order that this action is done automatically. For example if the user selects '2minutes', Twitter must be checked every 2 minutes automatically and the results be refreshed.

Can someone help with some general explanations how can I do this?

Comment: take a look at this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf in your case `interval="myBean.someIntervalNum"` and so on...

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! Exactly what I needed and I am already using Primefaces. You can add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [Poll - Start/Stop](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf)

in your case

```
interval="#{myBean.someIntervalNum}"
```

and so on...